# My drawer menu on Android Studio keeps drawing on the left side when I set Gravity to END

Tags: java, android

I have an Android Studio Java project that has a toolbar, Bottom Nav and I am trying to make a drawer. I want the drawer to be on the right side of the screen and I can't figure out what's wrong. It draws on the left side and then gives an error when I click it.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                                    Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 7316                                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity RIGHT                                                                                                       at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1803)                                                                                                    at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1789)                                                                                                    at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.lambda$onCreate$0(MainActivity.java:65)                                                                                                       at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$hstk_Vs4CoATG7lbeBRzsxiUSIQ(Unknown Source:0)                                                                                                      at com.example.myapp.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onNavigationItemSelected(Unknown Source:2)                                                                                                  at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:217)                                                                                                      at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:834)                                                                                                  at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)                                                                                                  at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:985)                                                                                                     at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:416)                                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7441)                                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7418)                                                                                                   at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:835)                                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28676)                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

I have a menu in my menu folder that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/hb_EditProfile"
        android:title="Edit Profile" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/hb_password"
        android:title="Password &amp; Security" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/hb_help"
        android:title="Help &amp; Support" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/hb_logout"
        android:title="Log Out" />
    <!-- Add more items as needed -->
</menu>
```

I added it to my activity_main.xml like this:

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:logo="@drawable/logo"
            app:title=" " />


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation">
        </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>```

And I set up my MainActivity.java like this:
````

```
private DrawerLayout drawer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here
        int id = item.getItemId();

        // TODO: Implement your actions for each menu item
        // ...

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        return true;
    });

    //Code for bottom nav.. which does work. 
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

```
Any help would be great! :)
```